# Remove padding between stackable grids in Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

Here's my SemanticUI HTML:

```
<div class="ui stackable two column grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui list">
            <div class="item">
                Item 1
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                Item 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui list">
            <div class="item">
                Item 3
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                Item 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is correctly producing the following at desktop resolutions:

```
Item 1          Item 3
Item 2          Item 4
```

However, at mobile resolutions (ie: when the stacking happens) it's displaying like this:

```
Item 1     
Item 2 
        <--- unwanted padding!
Item 3
Item 4
```

So, it's in the right order but each of the columns has a load of padding around it.

I know how to override the CSS to remove the padding manually, but I'd like to know if there's a way of achieving what I want to do with SemanticUI. It doesn't necessarily have to be a solution that uses lists or grids/columns as long as I can have two columns of lists on the desktop that turns into one uninterrupted list of items on mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I: **Semantic UI Way**

You can modify the SUI theming variables for this purpose. Here's how:

Modify `definitons/collections/grid.less`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @largestMobileScreen) {
  .ui.stackable.grid {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0em !important;
    margin-right: 0em !important;
  }
  .ui.stackable.grid > .row > .wide.column,
  .ui.stackable.grid > .wide.column,
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column.grid > .column,
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column.row > .column,
  .ui.stackable.grid > .row > .column,
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column:not(.row),
  .ui.grid > .stackable.stackable.row > .column {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0em 0em !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: (@stackableRowSpacing / 2) (@stackableGutter / 2) !important;
  }
```

This is the part that is adding 1rem of padding when you go below 768px. You can modify @stackableRowSpacing variable to be equal to the padding between Item 1 and 2

**II: CSS modifications:**

You can test out the solution with this CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column:not(.row) {
    padding: 3px !important;
  }
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column:first-child {
    padding-top: 1rem !important;
  }
  .ui.stackable.grid > .column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
  }
}
```

Replace 3px with the padding between two Items in the same column.

I'd recommend just using the extra CSS code if the issue is localized (on one page). If you want to enforce global `padding` rules, modifying the theming variables are a good option.